# Backing up .PST's to the cloud effectively

Tags: networking, microsoft-outlook, backup, bandwidth

Medium sized business 2000 people.

Connected HP Backup is used to backup people’s data in HP’s Datacentre. 
We have 3 sites, 30Mb split across 3 sites, 10Mb each.

700 people per site (not exactly), our bandwidth is all used because of Connected HP Backup. 
We’re using QoS but due to the amount of people backing up, modifying files it’s just all backup traffic.

The most problematic files are .PST’s (Outlook Archive Files) but this is a critical file we need to backup, we cannot exempt it. Connected HP Backup does not know how to read .PST files so if the file was modified by 1KB it would still upload let’s say the whole 1.5GB’s. That’s not efficient at all.
We also do not want to back up on file shares locally in case the user wants to access the backups from home, as It would use our upload bandwidth.

Question is; what would be a better way of backing up a lot of user’s data without taking all of the bandwidth? Is there a program that can read the small amount of modifications and instead of re-uploading a whole 1.5GB’s it’d just upload the 1KB edit?

EDIT: We have Office 365 however Office becomes slow and unresponsive when the .OST file reaches around 3.5GB, and if the mail box breaks for some reason you'd have to download potentially 30GB's of data over a 10Mb/s shared network. Which isn't ideal.

Comment: From experience... don't give users small mailboxes so that they have no option but to use PSTs to archive. My work place has gone from 1GB mailboxes (hosted in-house) to Office365 where users get 50GB mailboxes so that archiving isn't done anywhere near as frequently - even our heaviest of users will take a fair while to fill a 50GB mailbox (that doesn't mean to say they should take that as a sign to never have a clear out once in a while!). It also gives the users the ability to access their mailboxes wherever they go and on whatever device they please.

Comment: I should have included this, apologies, we do actually have Office 365 and the 50GB of storage, however if a mailbox breaks, which isn't a uncommon thing, it'll have to redownload 10+ GB's of data. We're also experiencing issues with the size of .OST files, becoming more than 3.5GB's in size, where mailbox just becomes really slow, and unresponsive.

Comment: If you're having bandwidth issues, too, then you should really consider getting a better connection, too... 700 people per site on a 10Mbps connection... sounds fairly horrible to me... We have multiple sites with similar concurrent users and we struggled with a 1Gbps!

Comment: It would be nice, but 30Mb/s asynchronous is already expensive, especially with BT in the UK. I'm trying to find a good idea, I was told OneDrive Business has the ability to check .PST's and upload the modified portion.

Comment: I would strongly urge you to not sync PSTs across a WAN/OneDrive.... even across a LAN is dangerous enough with PSTs... if the link drops and a user is using the file then it could toast the file... if you already sync PSTs/OSTs across a LAN/WAN then this probably where all your problems have begun... Honestly, your current setup is not doing you any favours. An additional solution would be for users to use the Office365 WebApp (OWA) and don't let them use Outlook. You can open shared mailboxes in OWA, you can have signatures, add attachments, AutoComplete/recently typed email addresses etc.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into this. We've tried to push Outlook Web App, however people just turn to the easiest solution unfortunately. Also, did not know you could add shared mailboxes via OWA. This is a must. This sounds like the better solution honestly. May I ask why you disagree with OneDrive for Business besides the dropped connection?

Comment: I don't disagree with OneDrive for Business - I use it regularly - but you should not, ever, use a LAN/WAN/OneDrive sync for PSTs lol... because of how frequently they can change and the various lock mechanisms Outlook put on the file can cause corruption easily. We have staff that try it, most fail and come crying to us when their PSTs corrupt because they didn't listen to us... Hence why we've moved to Office365 and we've created a GPO to prevent the creation and opening of PST files because it's just not worth it anymore when the better solution is a much bigger mailbox from the start.

Comment: Ah understood, thanks for your help Chris. I'll see about buying more bandwidth and using the online version over the desktop application.

Answer (score 2):

I could suggest you to try CloudBerry Backup.
It has an option called "block-level backup" - allows to backup only changed parts of files.

More infomration here:

http://www.cloudberrylab.com/blog/block-level-backup-across-all-cloud-storages/

It aslo provides an ability to limit your bandwidth according to the schedule, it could also be useful for you.

You can see more details here:

http://www.cloudberrylab.com/blog/cloudberry-backup-intelligent-bandwidth-scheduler/

If you have any questions, pelase let me know.

Regards,
Vlad,
CloudBerry Lab